# Creating an epidemiological prevalence table in R using dataset

Tags: r, statistics, analytics, gtsummary

I have previously created a prevalence table in SAS but I am trying to replicate it in R. I have attached description and image of target table below.

I having trouble creating a simple table the shows prevalence by age and sex. I have tried using various methods including the gt_summary package with the following code but no luck.

```
#prevalence of Chagas by age and sex
df_linked6 %>%
  select(Age_interval, Sex, Confirmatory_results) %>%
  tbl_summary(
    by = Sex,
    label = list(Age_interval ~ "Age (yrs)”, 
                 Confirmitory_results ~ “Confirmed"),
    percent = "row",
    statistic = list(Age_interval ~ "{n}/{N} ({p}%)"),)
```

I have created the table in SAS before but cant seem to replicate it in R. My variables for column 1 is Age_interval for 10 year levels. The next column Id like is a an overall summary of the prevalence, and the following two columns correspond to my Sex variable. For each cell I'd like the prevalence of my disease which can be calculated by my Confirmatory_results variable.

I have attached my target table. Any help/suggestions would greatly help! Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Rather than `tbl_summary()`, I think you'll have better luck with `gsummary::tbl_cross()`.  If you update your post with a minimal reproducible example, aka a reprex, the community could assist further. https://reprex.tidyverse.org/

Comment: Welcome to SO, jhar123! Questions on SO (especially in R) do much better if they are reproducible and self-contained. By that I mean including attempted code (good start here, please be explicit about non-base packages), sample representative data (perhaps via `dput(head(x))` or building data programmatically (e.g., `data.frame(...)`), possibly stochastically), perhaps actual output (with verbatim errors/warnings) versus intended output. Refs: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269, [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info.